# Can I mock an individual function that is imported into the module I import with jest?

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs, supertest

I have written a nodeJS module `mymodule.js` that imports the sqlite module. I now want to write some jest tests so I imported `my module.js` into my jest test script but want to mock some of the `sqlite` functions such as `get()` in a couple of tests. All the examples and tutorials assume we are directly importing the library we want to mock. Can I mock the sqlite functions without creating a system-wide mock even though I am not importing the module?

Comment: Yes, you can. The way it should be done depends on a library (sqlite) and how it's used. Consider providing the code you're testing and tests themselves.

Comment: As sqlite is a bit more complicated to mock please add your code so its clear what you need to mock.